# How to get information from TouchEvent?

Tags: android

I need help about getting information from TouchEvent. For instance, if I draw a line, I need information where ACTION_DOWN has started and where that action has finished (for instance: started: top, finished: left).
I included image so this can be clearer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbCsc.png

Here is the code (for drawing):

```
    package com.mmilosanovic.trafficcounting;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class JunctionView extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    public JunctionView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track the motion yourself.  Create class variables like `float startX, startY` and assign to them when you get `ACTION_DOWN`.  Then you can compare to those values when you get `ACTION_UP`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to get information that ACTION has started at top and has finished at left side of screen?